# ggplotly distorts marker sizes and line thickness, ignores hjust/vjust

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I noticed many differences when the same plot is rendered through `ggplot2` *vs* `plotly`. It includes such basic things as marker sizes, line thickness and text labels adjustment.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
data(iris)

p1 <-
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_text(x=5.5, y=2, label='\u25BA',color='red',hjust='left',vjust='bottom')+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5,6), ylim = c(2,3))+
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = -3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))

p1
ggplotly(p1)
```

[image: Two outputs of the same plot]

You can see at this example that all the markers are about 1/3 larger, line is 3x more thick, `hjust` and `vjust` of a text label (red triangle here) are ignored. Is there any way to fix this besides manually adjusting all the parameters for each layer?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that converting a ggplot object using ggplotly will not always yield the same exact output as you would get with plotly directly.  However, you can adjust your point size and line width according to what you expect in ggplotly.  Also, play with hjust and vjust being 0 or 1, see where the text appear for `geom_text`.  Using `annotate` instead of `geom_text` displays x and y values as shown below, when you hover over the red triangle.

Try this

```
mycolor <- c("green","blue","red")
myshape <- c(21, 22, 23)

p1 <-
  ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  # geom_text(x=5.5, y=2, label='abc',color='red',hjust=1,vjust=0)+ ## '\u25BA'
  annotate(geom="text", x=5.5, y=2, label='\u25BA',color='red') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(4,7), ylim = c(2,5))+
  scale_color_manual(values=mycolor) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=myshape) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = -3, lwd=0.5)+
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes=list(color=myshape) ),    
         color= 'none')   ## do not display color legend
         
p1
ggplotly(p1)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you for the input. Unfortunately `hjust`/`vjust` as 0-1 do not work either, and in my real plots `x` and `y` for all markers are coming from the dataset (through `aes()`), so I can't set them explicitly and play around. For now I use a workaround of adding some number to `x` coordinate but it's really not a good solution, it does not work when the plot is resized/rescaled.

Comment: Similarly, adjusting markers' size and line width is what I currently do and what I would like to avoid: that way I have to make two versions for each plot (one for `ggplot` and one for `plotly`) - having many different plots, each with 10-15 layers, it becomes a mess...

Comment: I have the same problem.  Also, caption (footnote) in ggplot is fine; when converting ggplot object to ggplotly the caption is overlapping on the bottom legend.